# How to compare large integers represented as exponents

Tags: prime-numbers, exponentiation, integers

I have large integers that can only be factored into 2, 3 and 5, which are known as [5-smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number). Since they are extremely large, I want to represent each such number as a triplet of exponents; for example, $360 = 2^33^25$ will be represented as $(3,2,1)$.

My question is: given 2 such triplets, how to compare them to determine which one is larger? If this is difficult to do, are there other ways to compare extremely large 5-smooth numbers?

Comment: Express $\log(x)-\log(y)$ using base $2$ logarithms. Rather than using float values for those logarithms, you may want to use good rational approximations.  Thus, according to Maple,
$$ {\frac{2457612485764860659689096693368334799470374920545}{
1550580840017760484596044169668976645517675504708}}
< \log_2(3) < {\frac{936021361635908802301548714003935992446832785637}{
590563727034563984957508038059757509394880543411}}
$$

Comment: and 
$${\frac{1204568865001710592015862905306226418173599816}{
518779572741310365626237421988716170017581551}}
< \log_2(5) < {\frac{205916591576555070446017474313267359452081159}{
88683448910395378076532076391025709452737513}}
$$
where these come from continued fractions.

Comment: note that   the gcd is given immediately by the minimum exponent  for each prime. Diving both numbers by the gcd means that, in the general case,  you have a choice of three types,  one of $2^a 3^b ? 5^c\; , \; \;  3^a 5^b ? 2^c \; , \; \;  5^a 2^b ? 3^c $

Comment: @RobertIsrael Could you please elaborate on how to use the rational approximations of $\log_2(3)$ and $\log_2(5)$ to compute the results? IMO, the denominators are too large to reduce the fractions to the common denominator. Thanks.

Comment: @WillJagy what does the $?$ in $2^a3^b?5^c$ mean? Thanks.

Comment: The question mark means unknown inequality. The same as your original question, but with smaller exponents,  also three or more exponents zero.

Answer (score 3):

Compare the logarithm of their ratio:

$$\log \left( \dfrac{2^{a_1}3^{b_1}5^{c_1}}{2^{a_2}3^{b_2}5^{c_2}} \right)
= (a_1-a_2) * \log 2 + (b_1-b_2) * \log 3 + (c_1-c_2) * \log 5
 $$

So if you keep the values of the three logarithms around, you can just subtract the triples, take their weighted sum, and check if the final value is greater than or less than zero.

Also note that it doesn't matter what base you use for the logarithms, so you might as well use $\log_2$, as it eliminates one multiplication. And @RobertIsrael has given you some pointers in the comments on how you might want to "implement" the other two logs.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to implement the rational approximations to $\log_2(3)$ and $\log_2(5)$ described by @RobertIsrael as the denominators are too large to be even stored as long long integer type.

Comment: You don't *have* to use them - you can just use floating point values. You just need to be aware that floating point values usually include a little bit of error, and if your two numbers are very close together you might not get a reliably conclusive answer. This corresponds to the problem one always gets when switching to floating point: it's hard to tell if a very small small number is positive, negative, or zero.

Comment: Me, I would just use floating point values for the logarithms, but be prepared for my `which_is_larger ()` function to sometimes return CANT_TELL. There can conceivably be a case where there are two 25,000 digit numbers that are the same for the first 24,995 digits. You'd have use something more than just a long long (maybe arbitrarily long BigInts?) to find which is bigger. You'll need to add more details, and what kind of number representation technology you're prepared to use, to go further. And maybe it becomes a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

For example, suppose you want to compare $x = 2^{18109} 3^{13311} 5^{78533}$ and
$y = 2^{1234} 3^{5678} 5^{91011}$.  Thus $\log_2(x/y) = 16875 + 7633\; \log_2(3) - 12478 \; \log_2(5)$.  Using the bounds in my comment, call them $a < \log_2(3) < b$ and $c < \log_2(5) < d$, and exact rational arithmetic
$$ \log_2(x/y) \ge 16875 + 7633\; a - 12478\; d = \frac{10692336877226592511500615697352249069160249067552360957604649661900932431026239389}{137510856707153011098323838512520736495133097760788393116779975825724269815133543514519711204} > 0$$
so $x > y$.